# Uploading and plotting two files on each other in shinymodules

Tags: r, shiny

I really need help with this issue. So, I'm trying to modulize an app, in the first module, I'm uploading two different files, in this case, observed data and simulated data.
which later on, on the next module (the plot module), they should create a plot on each other, so the observed data should be geom_point() and simulated data should be geom_line().
However,In the first module, both datasets can be read and displayed, but only one dataset is available in the plot module and in its selectInput()
I have come this far, it's not entirely correct, so, I would be grateful if I can get some help here.

```
UploadUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    "Upload File",
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput(ns("file1"), "Observed data",
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv"
                  )
        ),
        fileInput(ns("file2"), "sim data",
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv"
                  )


        ),
        tags$br(),
        checkboxInput(ns("header"), "Header", TRUE),
        radioButtons(
          ns("sep"),
          "Separator",
          c(
            Comma = ",",
            Semicolon = ";",
            Tab = "\t"
          ),
          ","
        ),
        radioButtons(
          ns("quote"),
          "Quote",
          c(
            None = "",
            "Double Quote" = '"',
            "Single Quote" = "'"
          ),
          '"'
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput(ns("contents")),
        br(),
        tableOutput(ns("contents_2"))
      )
    )
  )
}




UploadServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns

    data <- reactive({
      req(input$file1)

      inFile <- input$file1

      df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath,
                     header = input$header, sep = input$sep,
                     quote = input$quote
      )
      return(df)
    })


    data_2 <- reactive({
      req(input$file1)

      inFile <- input$file1

      df_2 <- read.csv(inFile$datapath,
                     header = input$header, sep = input$sep,
                     quote = input$quote
      )
      return(df_2)
    })







    output$contents <- renderTable({
      data()
    })

    output$contents_2 <- renderTable({
      data_2()
    })


    # return data
    data

    data_2

    }
  )
}

###############################################

PlotUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tabPanel("Visualisation",

           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               p("Observed data"),
               fluidRow(
                 column(6,
                        selectInput(ns('obsxcol'), 'X Variable', "",width=140)

                 ),
                 column(6,
                        selectInput(ns('obsycol'), 'Y Variable', "", selected = "",width=140)

                 )

               ),
               p("Simulated data"),
               fluidRow(
                 column(6,
                        selectInput(ns('simxcol1'), 'X Variable', "",width=140)


                 ),
                 column(6,
                        selectInput(ns('simycol1'), 'Y Variable', "", selected = "",width=140),

                 )

               ),
               fluidRow(
                 column(6,
                        checkboxInput(ns("logxobs"), "logX", FALSE, width=140)
                 ),
                 column(6,
                        checkboxInput(ns("logyobs"), "logY", FALSE, width=140)


                 )

               ),
               hr(),
               fluidRow(
                 actionButton(ns("plot_vis_1"), "Plot!")

               )

             ),
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput(ns('plotsim_1'))





               )


             )


  )





}

PlotServer <- function(id, df, df_2) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(df))
  stopifnot(is.reactive(df_2))

  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns



    observeEvent(df(),{

      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'obsxcol', label ='X vairable',
                        choices = names(df()), selected = names(df()))

      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'obsycol', label ='Y vairable',
                        choices = names(df()), selected = names(df())[2])



    })


    observeEvent(df_2(),{

      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'simxcol1', label ='X vairable',
                        choices = names(df_2()), selected = names(df_2()))

      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'simycol1', label ='Y vairable',
                        choices = names(df_2()), selected = names(df_2())[2])



    })
    
    
    plot_1<-reactive({
      graph2 <- ggplot() +
        geom_point(data = df, aes(.data[[input$obsxcol]], .data[[input$obsycol]]), size=1) +
        
        geom_line(data = df_2, aes(.data[[input$simxcol1]]/60, .data[[input$simycol1]])) +
        
        theme_bw()
      
      if(input$logyobs){
        graph2 <- graph2 + scale_y_log10()
      }
      
      if(input$logxobs){
        graph2 <- graph2 +  scale_x_log10()
      }
      
      
      graph2
      
    })  |> bindEvent(input$plot_vis_1)
    
    
    
    
    
    output$plotsim_1 <-renderPlot({
      plot_1()
    })
    




    }
  )
}


















ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Column Plot"),
  tabsetPanel(
    UploadUI("upload"),
    PlotUI("plot")


  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  upload <- UploadServer("upload")
  PlotServer("plot",df = upload,df_2 = upload )


})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: in R, function can return only one object and a module is technically a function. So you must do `return(list(data, data_2))` in `uploadServer`, and in server `upload <- UploadServer("upload")` and then `df = upload[[1]], df_2=upload[[2]]`

Comment: @gdevaux Thanks for the comment, I added return(list(data, data_2)) in the uploadServer Module, and df = upload[[1]], df_2=upload[[2]] in the PlotServer() so now, both selectInput() for observerd and simulated data works. however, when I try to plot, I get Error in f: unused argument (list()).

Comment: @gdevaux Do I have to add return(list(data, data_2)) somewhere else too?

Comment: Now you've updated your upload module, you need to update your plot module to handle the new format of input it's being given.  Previously, it was getting a single reactive.  Now it's geting a reactive list.  So, in your plot server function, you need only one additional parameter, `dfList`, say.  You then refer to the elements of that list, within the server function, as `dfList()[[1]]` and `dfList()[[2]]`.  Though it would, IMHO, be better to name the list elements.

Comment: @EnriqueGG sorry that's the best i could do, i can't run any code right now so i cannot go further in the help

Comment: @Limey Thanks for the explanation, it was a little bit hard to follow, so now, I have uploaded the upload module, and the uploaded  files can interact with the selectInput() in the plot module, after that I don't understand, What I should add in the plotServer() or within its plotServer module.

Comment: @Limey I tried as far as I could understand, but still, get "unused argument (list())" when I click on the plot button.

Comment: It's impossible to test your code because you haven't given us any data to work with.  Perhaps the simplest thing to do is to replace the `read.csv()`s in your upload server with the content of some sample csv files.  That will enable the transfer of data between the two modules to be tested.